# Использовать debounce вместо setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Как переписать на debounce вместо setTimeout?

Нужно наверное чтобы debounce возвращал промис

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce

Поведение должно быть аналогично этому https://codesandbox.io/s/wy7z7q5zx5 с  интервалом 300 mc

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const asyncValidation = memoize( async value => {
  await sleep(500);
  try {
   …..
  } catch (err) {
   …..
  }
});
```

Comment: стоит добавить что такое debounce, и что вообще должно происходить в коде

Comment: debounce из lodash библиотеки например

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce

Comment: добавь описание в сам вопрос, плюс описание того _что вообще должно происходить в коде_

Comment: Поведение должно быть аналогично этому https://codesandbox.io/s/wy7z7q5zx5 с интервалом 300 mc

+ добавил в вопрос

Comment: попробуй сделать описание словами, а не ссылкой: непонятно что именно должен демонстрировать пример и что надо сделать, чтобы увидеть ожидаемое поведение, и, главное, в чем именно это ожидаемое поведение заключается.

Comment: Добавьте [mcve], пожалуйста. И опишите желаемое поведение. «Хочу как тут» - это не описание. По ссылке слишком много кода.

Comment: вместо await sleep(300) в коде выше нужно использовать debounce

Comment: нельзя использовать `debounce` вместо _await sleep(300)_, так как `debounce` возвращает функцию, а `await sleep` - тормозит выполнение _текущей_ функции.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что такое debounce:

```js
const debounce = (fn, ms) => {
  let dfn = (...args) => {
    let rest = +dfn.next - Date.now();
    dfn.next = (dfn.next ? dfn.next : Date.now()) + ms;
    setTimeout(() => fn(...args), rest > 0 ? rest + ms : ms);
  }
  return dfn;
}


let fn = debounce(
  i => console.log(i, Date.now()),
  200
);
for (let i = 1; i <= 30; ++i) {
  setTimeout(() => fn(i))
}
console.log(30, 'calls queued');
```

То попробую угадать что Вам нужно от sleep:

```js
const debounce = (fn, ms) => {
  let dfn = (...args) => {
    let rest = +dfn.next - Date.now();
    dfn.next = (dfn.next ? dfn.next : Date.now()) + ms;
    return new Promise(ok => 
       setTimeout(
         () => ok(fn(...args)), 
         rest > 0 ? rest + ms : ms
       ));
  }
  return dfn;
}

const getSleep = ms => debounce(
  () => Promise.resolve(), 
  ms
);
const sleep = getSleep(200);

(async() => {
  let start = Date.now();
  await sleep();
  await sleep();
  await sleep();
  await Promise.all([sleep(), sleep(), sleep()]);
  console.log(`wake up after ${Date.now() - start}ms`);  // 1200ms = 200 * 6
})()
```